# XAMPP localhost is not accessable through iPhone

Tags: iphone, windows, apache, xampp, port

I've done quite a bit of Googling to try to find a solution for my issue but none have worked. Basically, I cannot get localhost to work on my phone (it simply won't load, getting the "Safari can't load this page" error). Details:

- I'm using my IPv4 address (192.168.1.x) in trying to access my XAMPP server.
- I use a static IP address (to use Google's DNS).
- Apache is running on default ports (80 for http & 443 for SSL).
- My PC is connected to the router through cable.
- HomeGroup is disabled.
- Using Windows 10 64-bit, XAMPP version 3.2.2.

What I've tried:

- Added firewall rules to allow all inbound connections to ports 80 and 433.
- Changed the following (in httpd.conf):

  ```
  <Directory />
     AllowOverride none
     Require all denied
  </Directory>
  ```

  to:

  ```
  <Directory />
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- Changed all `Require local` lines to `Require all granted` in httpd-xampp.conf
- Tried using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) but couldn't get it to work. Kept getting "Tunnel x not found error).
- Tried changing Apache ports but that caused a whole another mess. Localhost completely stopped working (kept getting the "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error when I tried accessing the server on my computer).
- Yes, I always restarted Apache & MySQL services between each change.

One thing to note, the SSL port kinda works on the phone using the following address: 192.168.1.x:443 but I get a "400 BAD REQUEST" error.. So that's something.

Comment: try like this "https://192.168.1.x"

Comment: That did not make a difference.